# How to assign the output of solve in mupad to a set of valuables?

Tags: math-software

How to assign the output of solve in mupad to a set of valuables? For example, ss:=solve([x+2*y=1, 3*x+y=2],[x,y]); The result of ss[1][1] is x=3/5. I would like to assign some variable a to the value of x in ss:=solve([x+2*y=1, 3*x+y=2],[x,y]); How could I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use VectorForm option in solve.